# How to dynamically generate Cypress tests based on data received in `before()`?

Tags: cypress

[This example](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html#Can-I-run-the-same-tests-on-multiple-subdomains) is very close to what I need, except that the `urls` are not known ahead of time (can't hardcode them).

The `urls` are generated in the `before()` hook by running a script:

```
before(() => {
  cy.exec(<run script that generates a temporary urls.json file>);
  cy.readFile("./urls.json")....
});
```

How could I dynamically generate separate tests based on the generated `urls.json`?

The reason they need to be separate tests is [this](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/944).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The test enumerator `.forEach()` runs before the `before()` hook, but that's ok if you know exactly how many urls you need to process.

In the Cypress example you cited, setting urls in `before()`.

```js
let urls = []; 

describe('Logo', () => {

  before(() => {
    cy.exec('npm run generator')
      .then(() => {  // writing the file will be async
        cy.readFile("./urls.json").then(data => {
          urls = data;
      });
    });
  })

  Cypress._.range(0, 2).forEach(index => {       // only need the number of tests here

    it(`Should display logo #${index}`, () => {
      const url = urls[index]                    // runs after before()
      cy.visit(url)
      ...
    })
  })
})
```

Note, `url` can't be in the test description any more, but index can.

If the number of urls is unknown, it is still technically possible by setting the test enumerator to a maximum, but the results in the log are messy. Unused test slots still show as passing.

---

The basic problem is the generator script needs to run in the Cypress Node process, but the spec runs in the browser process.

But ipc communication between browser and node is done via async `cy.*` commands that can only run in callbacks, which can only run during the execution phase.

You would be better off running the generator script externally, something like

```
"scripts": {
  "gen:test": "npm run generator & cypress open"
}
```

then using a simple `require()` to pick up the data

```js
const data = require('./urls.json')
let urls = data.urls;
const testCount = data.urls.length;  

describe('Logo', () => {

  before(() => {
    // not required
  })

  Cypress._.range(0, testCount).forEach(index => {

  or

  urls.forEach((url, index) => {
```

Comment: Really useful post. I also observed that '.forEach' works in this mechanism but not the regular 'for' loop.

Comment: Regarding the top code snippet.... I imagine there is no way (in the presumed scenario where URLs are not known beforehand, but an upper number considered), that we can somehow accomodate the 'URL' info in the test name (instead of just the # variable as postfix to "Should display logo")? I am wondering if we can have more informative test names when using the approach. My guess is no, as the info isn't available beforehand.